# Inline instantiation of a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I would like to know why this piece of code

```
vdcArray.add(new JSONObject().put("Nome", utente.getNome()));
```

produces different result from separated instantiation like this:

```
JSONObject nomeVdc = new JSONObject();
nomeVdc.put("Nome", utente.getNome());
vdcArray.add(nomeVdc);
```

In the first case I receive [null] rather than [Nome:pippo]

Why ? Technically the would produce the same result, the JSON object come from 
org.json.simple.* library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case, you are adding result of this `new JSONObject().put("Nome", utente.getNome())` call.

Equivalent implementation would be like:

```
JSONObject nomeVdc = new JSONObject();
Object temp = nomeVdc.put("Nome", utente.getNome());
vdcArray.add(temp);
```

Comment: sorry, I still miss something. Can you explain me better ? Do you mean temp is null in the first scenario ?

Comment: @Fjordo, Sachin is saying that the put method returns a value. You are then putting the return value of put into the JSON object. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) for more information